# angular ng-repeat : filter doesn't work in symfony twig view

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-filter

I build an app for my company accounting.
I list all operations for an account, from json with a ng-repeat.
Ng-repeat work great, but the problem is :

I want add an input for filter by name of operation.
The filter don't work, and after lot of search, I don't understand why.

The code of my app.js (angular) :

```
//app.js

var app = angular.module('app', [], function($interpolateProvider){
  $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
  $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
});

app.controller('MainController', function ($scope, Account) {
  $scope.ops = {};

  $scope.showOps = function(account_id) {
    Account.get(account_id)
      .success(function(data){
         $scope.ops = data;
      })
      .error(function(data){
         console.log(data);
      });
   }
})

app.factory('Account', function($http){
   return {
     get : function(account_id) {
        return $http.get('/api/operations/' + account_id);
    }
 }
});
```

And code of my twig template :

```
{% block body -%}
  <div data-ng-init="showOps({{ entity.id }});">
    <div class="account-head">
      <h1>Compte</h1>
      {{ form(delete_form) }}
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <span class="account-name">{{ entity.name }}</span>
          <span class="account-actions">
            <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{{    path('account_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Editer</a>
          </span>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input placeholder="Search" data-ng-model="query.name" ng-disabled="isDisabled" type="text">
<div data-ng-repeat="op in ops | filter: query">
     <p><% op.type %></p>
     <p><% op.name %></p>
     <p><% op.montant %></p>
     <hr>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

This should filter results when the value of the input change 
(example by me : http://chalasr.github.io/#/works)
But I don't have any reaction when I write into the input.
I have tryed some differents filters like :

```
<div data-ng-repeat="op in ops | filter: {name: someNameInResult}">
<div data-ng-repeat="op in ops | filter: {query: query}">
```

But it does'nt work !
Thanks by advance if you can help me !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem.

Solution for filter data objects like this:

```
  $scope.items = {
    0: {date: new Date('12/23/2013')},
    1: {date: new Date('12/23/2011')},
    2: {date: new Date('12/23/2010')},
    3: {date: new Date('12/23/2015')}
  };
```

Just add [angular-toArrayFilter](https://github.com/petebacondarwin/angular-toArrayFilter) as dependency in your app, and use it :

```
//Markup:
<div data-ng-init="showOps({{ entity.id }});">
  <div class="account-head">
    <h2>Compte: {{ entity.name }}</h2>
    {{ form(delete_form) }}
    <a class="btn btn-default btn-sm" href="{{ path('account_edit', { 'id': entity.id }) }}">Editer</a>
  </div>
  <input type="text" ng-model="query.name">
  <div ng-repeat="ops in ops | toArray | filter: query">
    <p><% ops.type %></p>
    <p><% ops.name %></p>
    <p><% ops.montant %></p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
```

Thank's all for your help, I think other persons can have this problem and they can found the solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The model your filtering is named `query.name`, so change your ng-repeat too:

```
data-ng-repeat="op in ops | filter: query.name"
```

Comment: Thans for your answer but it's doesn't work, no reaction .
I don't understand the problem :'(

Comment: Can you post a example of the data that ng-repeat is iterating on. Is that ng-repeat working without any filter?